# Unable to perform join in mongodb using a package and code specified in https://pypi.org/project/mongojoin/

Tags: python, mongodb, join, lookup

Unable to execute $lookup in mongodb. I need to perform join in mongodb using Python, but the code and package specified in https://pypi.org/project/mongojoin/ is not working.
Also, can $lookup be run from mongoshell, and if yes, how?

I am using the following code:

```
from mongojoin.mongojoin import MongoJoin, MongoCollection

c = MongoCollection("test", "c", ["name", "add", "prod_id"], {prod_id : "123456"})
p = MongoCollection("test", "p", [ "prod_id", "pname", "pcost",], {prod_id : "123456"})
aggregator = MongoJoin(c, p, ["prod_id"])
result = aggregator.inner()
print(result)
```

Getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\nm21\jd1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mongojoin.mongojoin import MongoJoin, MongoCollection
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mongojoin\mongojoin.py", line 10, in <module>
    from processdata import CollectionsProcessedData
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processdata'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have converted the cursors to lists then appended one list with another.
It worked...

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTUGh.png)
Download the zip file of mongojoin from GIT and paste the files in same loaction of the file from where you are trying to import the mongojoin packages.
use Imports as Following:
**

- from mongojoin import MongoJoin
- from mongojoin import MongoCollection

**

As for example mongoread_Q is the file from which i am trying join and init.py, mongocollection.py , processdata.py are files from MongoCollection packages extracted in same Location.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Update the below changes to mongo.py library after installing "pip install process-data & pip install sklearn"

```
"from process_data.setup.collections import CollectionsProcessedData"
```